# How to set same appearance for spinner in XML design?

Tags: android, xml, spinner, appearance

I'm using two spinner in my activity but each spinner having different appearance. Anyone can help me to fix this kind of error???
[This is first spinner image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ydVf.png)

[This is second spinner image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekGPS.png) (Please see the image)

```
String [] values =
            {"All Town","Paris","Kodambakkam","Nungambakkam","T.Nagar","Egmore"};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.town);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    String [] values1 =
            {"Select Doctor","Doctor1","Doctor2","Doctor3","Doctor4"};
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.doctor);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/town" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/doctor" /></LinearLayout>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: show your `ArrayAdapter` code for both spinners

Comment: post your layout.xml,style.xml and your arrayadapter

Comment: Akash Pate you are right. I fixed my error!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on second spinner... you have pass first adapter object to second adapter

```
String [] values1 =
        {"Select Doctor","Doctor1","Doctor2","Doctor3","Doctor4"};
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.doctor);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values1);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```